# turning on and off border radius on jquery click event

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

There are few divs. I need to change the border radius of them with click event. i have managed to change the border radius only once. When someone click on a div, the  border radous should be changed to 50%, And click on the same div again, applied border radius should remove.

And while there is a border changed div and if click on another div border of the changed div should remove and border radius should applied to clicked div. Which means there must be only one border radius applied div at a time.

I have this code

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hq6TQ/)

**HTML**

```
<div></div>

<div></div>

<div></div>

<div></div>
```

**ANd this css**

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #000;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
}
```

**also this jquery code**

```
$('div').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        $(this).css('border-radius', '50%');
    });
});
```

help me please, on this.. i have no idea about how to do this..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a class for that:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Hq6TQ/10/)

```
$('div').click(function(){
    if($(this).is('.radius')){$(this).removeClass('radius'); return;}
    $(this).addClass('radius').siblings().removeClass('radius');
});


div.radius {
    border-radius:50%
}
```

Comment: @Mr.ZerotoHero this one doesn't remove the rounded border if the selected DIV already has such border, take a look at my updated answer below.

Comment: @haynar and roasted One more question if i wrap these divs by using other elements such as ul, etc it stops working. Could you check this link please http://jsfiddle.net/Hq6TQ/12/

Answer (score 2):

I have updated your code adding CSS classes: http://jsfiddle.net/Hq6TQ/7/

```
div.round-border {
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

and adding it using jQuery:

```
$(this).addClass("round-border");
```

P.S. you don't need to iterate over each div element and bind events, you can just use the following snippet:

```
$('div').click(function(){
    // do whatever you need here
});
```

**UPDATE**: so far [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Hq6TQ/8/) is what you've initially asked for, I didn't read your question well.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to provide more divs than this. So you should user a class to select them.
I've updated your code and give you this function:

```
$('div.radius').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        $('div.radius').css('border-radius','0');
        $(this).css('border-radius', '50%');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/C23a2/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div').toggle(function(){
    $(this).css('border-radius', '50%');
});
```

Comment: If i click on another div while there is previously border radius applied div, that prviously applied border radius should remove :) how do i do that

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need to do each for a click event. Just use click directly. Then:

```
$('div').click(function(){
    $(this).css('border-radius', $(this).css('border-radius') == '50%' ? '0px' : '50%');
});
```

A (better) alternative would be to use `toggleClass()` like some people here suggested.

Answer (score 0):

JQUERY:

```
$('div').click(function () {
    $('div').removeClass('radius')
    $(this).addClass('radius');
});
```

CSS:

```
div.radius {
    border-radius:50%
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Hq6TQ/9/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, working good.

```
$('div').each(function () {
    $(this).click(function () {

        if ($(this).css("border-radius") == "0px") {
            $(this).css('border-radius', '50%');
        } else {
            $(this).css('border-radius', '0');
        }
    });
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/Hq6TQ/11/)